# Numeric Keypad on Extended Keyboard Doesn't Work in Terminal and There's No NumLock Key

Tags: terminal, keyboard, macos

When the Terminal window is in focus, pressing any of the numeric keys (0-9, the . key or the enter key ) generates a beep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing the "clear" button on the numeric keypad. If that doesn't work, try SHIFT+Clear.

Comment: the hell does this do ? and how did you find out that it works ?

Comment: It’s the same as pressing NUM LOCK. Trial and error. I was desperate to get my numeric keypad working, but it would just beep at me.

Comment: Fair enough, that was pretty random